# Add the values as a list element in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
dict1={'scope1': 'manager', 'scope2': 'om'}
```

I want that if I have another `"scope2"`  and values as `"fm"` in the for loops evaluation, then the "scope2" keys value should now become = `['om', 'fm']`.

Comment: you can't have another "scope2" in the same dictionary, it will replace the existing "scope2" value

Comment: @Ankit If my answer helped you or solved your question. Please mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1 = defaultdict(list)
dict1['scope1'].append('manager')
dict1['scope2'].append('om')
dict1['scope2'].append('fm')
```

If you print dict1, the result looks like

```
{'scope1': ['manager'], 'scope2': ['om','fm']}
```

Answer (score 1):

given this

```
dict1={'scope1': 'manager', 'scope2': 'om'}
```

Let's assumed you have another `scope2` somewhere else, you want to add it to the existing dictionary

Your key must be `list` to start with so that it can take multiple values

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict1 = defaultdict(list) # you can create list values this way 
...           #add contents
...           #add contents
dict1 = {'scope1': ['manager'], 'scope2': ['om']}
```

to append a new value just  do

```
dict1['scope2'].append('fm')
# {'scope1': ['manager'], 'scope2': ['om', 'fm']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i jumped too soon for help.
Got that

we can easliy append to the dictionary key's value and have the different value of the same key added as list